# Select multiple devuelve undefined

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un CRUD, a la hora de crear tengo un select multiple y quiero que se puedan seleccionar y guardar, pero el JS me devuelve undefined al ver que trae.

```
<option value="${item.id_curso}" class="curso_interes">${item.nombre}</option>
```

Hice un alert para poder ver el valor y me salta undefined

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName("curso_interes").value)
```

Answer (score 3):

A ver si miramos un poquito más la documentación... Aunque en este caso incluso atendiendo al propio nombre del método uno se puede dar cuenta: getElement**s**ByClassName().

El método `getElementsByClassName()` devuelve una colección de elementos, no un elemento. Por tanto, no puedes obtener la propiedad `value` directamente de esa colección.

Literalmente, esto es lo que devuelve, según la documentación:
*A live HTMLCollection of found elements.*

Tendrías que recorrer la colección y mostrar el valor de cada elemento:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('curso_interes');
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    alert(elements[i].value);
}
```

Tal vez te estás preguntando si existe un método `getElementByClassName()`, para obtener un único elemento. Y la respuesta es no, ya que puede haber varios elementos que tengan una misma clase, no tiene sentido, como por ejemplo sí lo tiene `getElementById()`, ya que se espera que sólo haya un elemento que tenga un determinado id.

Si en tu ejemplo sólo te interesan los elementos `option` seleccionados, y no todos, entonces puedes comprobar la propiedad `selected`:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('curso_interes');
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].selected) {
        alert(elements[i].value);
    }
}
```

Pero hay una forma aún más sencilla, que es mediante la propiedad `selectedOptions` de un elemento `select` múltiple. Por supuesto, primero tienes que obtener ese elemento, en vez de obtener los elementos según su `class`:

```
const elements = document.getElementById('idDeTuSelect').selectOptions;
```

Comment: +2 por *A ver si miramos un poquito más la documentación...*

Comment: Ahi todo bien, pero me trae todas las opciones, que le tengo que agregar para que me traiga solo las seleccionadas?

Comment: Puedes saber si un elemento `option` está seleccionado o no mediante su propiedad `selected`. He editado la respuesta para mostrarlo.